# Primefaces datatable: set row color from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

This question might appear as duplicate at the first time, but I didn't find someone else with the same problem.

We want to set specific row color in datatable. We found that there is only one "pretty" way to do it: using `rowStyleClass` attribute, which will apply styles from classes defined in `CSS` file.

But in our case, colors are obtained from the external database view and can be changed any time. It means that we can't define fixed styles in `CSS` file.

Unfortunately, there is no `rowStyle` attribute.
Any suggestions of how we can set row colors based on generated by bean hexadecimal value?

(we are using PF 5.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `rowStyle`. But, you can change `css` of the`styleClass` programmatically. Get `css` style from your backing bean.

**Don't** put the following `style` in css file. Just put it into your `jsf` page which show the `datatable`.

```
<style>
    .oddRowStyle {
        #{MyBean.oddRowStyle}
    }
    .evenRowStyle {
        #{MyBean.evenRowStyle}
    }
</style>
<p:dataTable .....  rowIndexVar="index" 
    rowStyleClass="#{(index mod 2) eq 0 ? 'evenRowStyle' : 'oddRowStyle'}"/>
```

MyBean.java

```
public String getOddRowStyle() {
    /*Change Your style as programmatically*/
    return "background-color: #F7F7F7!important ;";
}

public String getEvenRowStyle() {
    /*Change Your style as programmatically*/
    return "background-color: #05855F!important ;";
}
```

Comment: And you can even create the selectors dynamically in the bean...`return ".redRowStyle { background-color: red;}";` should work too. Just make sure you use its EL correctly in the css. And you can even create one full css part in your bean.