# Create CSS style in JSF page from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page created from a template where I want to add CSS styles from my backing bean, because some CSS attributes (like color, etc.) are read from a configuration database. The colors are used for `rowStyleClass` in a `p:dataTable` via `#{bean.getRowStyleClass(item)}`. This works only if the style tag is hard-coded within the page. If the style tag is retrieved from the backing bean, the returned string is just printed on the page as normal string.

[Kukeltje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4478047/kukeltje) mentioned in [Primefaces datatable: set row color from bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707287/primefaces-datatable-set-row-color-from-bean) that the bean could create the selectors dynamically with `return ".redBackgroundColor { background-color: #FF0000; !important; }"` and that the bean could create the full css part (which I do in `#{bean.styles}`) but this results also in a dataTable without colored rows.

template.xhtml

```
<html>
    <h:head>...</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="styles"/>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

page.xhtml

```
<html>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="styles">
            <!-- this works as expected -->
            <style type="text/css">
                .redBackgroundColor   { background-color: #FF0000; !important; }
                .blueBackgroundColor  { background-color: #00FF00; !important; }
                .greenBackgroundColor { background-color: #0000FF; !important; }
            </style>
            <!-- this does not work - it prints the string on the page --> 
            #{bean.styles}
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <!-- here comes the page content -->
            <p:dataTable var="item"
                         value={#bean.values}
                         rowStyleClass="#{bean.getRowStyleClass(item)}">
                ...
            </p:dataTable>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Bean.java

```
public class Bean {

    public String getStyles() {
        return new StringBuffer()
            .append("<style type=\"text/css\">")
            .append(".redBackgroundColor   { background-color: #FF0000; !important; }")
            .append(".blueBackgroundColor  { background-color: #00FF00; !important; }")
            .append(".greenBackgroundColor { background-color: #0000FF; !important; }") 
            .toString();
    }

    public String getRowStyleClass(Item item) {
        if (condition1) {
            return "redBackgroundColor";
        }
        if (condition2) {
            return "blueBackgroundColor";
        }
        if (condition3) {
            return "greenBackgroundColor";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

So, how can I create the styles in my backing bean and use them in the `p:dataTable rowStyleClass` attribute?

I am using Primefaces 6.0 on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final

Any hints welcome - Thank you!

Comment: Post your HTML output.

Comment: Seems you're missing a style endtag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when I change the page to:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #{bean.styles}
    </style>
```

and the bean method to:

```
public String getStyles() {
    return new StringBuffer()
        .append(".redBackgroundColor   { background-color: #FF0000; !important; }")
        .append(".blueBackgroundColor  { background-color: #00FF00; !important; }")
        .append(".greenBackgroundColor { background-color: #0000FF; !important; }")                 
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a style endtag?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but what does it hurt to have a global CSS file with all default backgrounds color in it and by creating the <div class="xx"> you determ the css to show?

Comment: @Jaqen: the missing endtag results from a copy-paste error - in the real code it was present!

Comment: awesome i was looking for exactly this